# How can I unistall a damge app

Tags: uninstall, system, error-handling, software-uninstall, wps-office

I have installed an old version of WPS Office. A few days ago, something went wrong and now I can't use software udpade among other problems.
Just I wanted to update WPS Office. I downloaded:

```
wps-office_9.1.0.4975~a19p1_i386.deb
```

When AppGrid tryed to install it, something fail.

I always get this error message:

```
E:The package wps-office:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I tryed to unistal from terminal, but alway shows me the same error.

I can't remove WPS-Office and I can't update it, even I can't udate my system o install others apps. What can I do?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Please edit your question and add the procedure you followed to install the software.

Comment: `... old version of WPS Office...` I'm assuming here that you need to install the latest version

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? And what version of WPS office are you trying to install?

Comment: WPS 9.1 It seems to be updated but I don't care. My major problem now is that I Can't update my system because any apps that i tryed to install, fail.

Comment: remove it like so: `sudo apt-get purge kingsoft-office` . then, `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Thanks but when I use sudo apt-get purge kingsoft-office

Comment: Thanks but when i use sudo apt-get purge kingsoft-office i gt that the progam is not installed buy I can run it. Baicly now any app from system setu is no working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install the deb file again

```
cd
wget http://kdl.cc.ksosoft.com/wps-community/download/a19/wps-office_9.1.0.4975~a19p1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/wps-office_9.1.0.4975\~a19p1_i386.deb
```

Now remove via

```
sudo apt-get remove wps-office
```